# iOS: Display IBeacon information in a SwiftUI List gives error "Value of type 'NSObject' has no member"

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ibeacon

I'm trying to create a List in SwiftUI that show the information from nearby beacons, but with no further success.

I can print the CLBeacon array info to the console, but when i try to print it out in a list it doesn't work.

Here is the full class that i'm using to start ranging and monitoring.

```swift
class Detector: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
    @Published var beaconData = [CLBeacon]()
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager?.delegate = self
        locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLBeaconRegion.self) {
                if CLLocationManager.isRangingAvailable() {
                    startScanning()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
        beaconData = beacons
    }
    
    func startScanning() {
        let uuid = UUID(uuidString: "<uuid>")!
        let constraint = CLBeaconIdentityConstraint(uuid: uuid)
        let beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(beaconIdentityConstraint: constraint, identifier: "beacon")

        locationManager?.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion)
        locationManager?.startRangingBeacons(satisfying: constraint)
    }
    
}
```

I store the beacons data into to CLBeacon array `beaconData`. The data from this array is what i will use in the View.

Now for the part that confuse me, a lot.

In my view, if a **print** the `beaconData` to the console, it works. The whole object or just a property works.
But if i want to print it in the app in a List it does not work. For example the UUID, i get the error `Value of type 'NSObject' has no member 'uuid'`

```swift
struct PositionOverview: View {
    @StateObject var detector = Detector()
    
    var body: some View {
        // This works
        detector.beaconData.forEach{beacon in
            print(beacon.uuid)
        }
        
        // This does not work
        return List(detector.beaconData, id: \.self){beacon in
            Text(beacon.uuid)
        }
        
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why this doesn't work? I'm missing something?
Did read something that the CLBeacon has internal properties of NSObject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Text` takes a `String` and you're trying to send it a `UUID`. That should result in a different compilation error, but my suspicion is that this will still resolve it.

Also, you probably want to use `.uuid` for the `List` `id` parameter:

```
struct PositionOverview: View {
    @StateObject var detector = Detector()
    
    var body: some View {
        List(detector.beaconData, id: \.uuid) { beacon in
            Text(beacon.uuid.uuidString)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You sir, are a genius! Jesus such an easy error..
Thank you so much! Been struggling with this for ages. 

According to the UUID as id. Partly right. All the beacons has the same ID. But a nice catch anyway!